# Accuracy of non-central chi-squared distribution implementation in scipy

Tags: python, scipy

The implementation of the non-central chi-squared distribution in scipy (scipy.stats.ncx2, scipy.special.chndtr) is not accurate for large values of the non-centrality parameter. E.g. consider

```
from scipy.stats import ncx2 

print(ncx2.cdf(1200,2,1000))
print(ncx2.cdf(1500,2,1000))
print(ncx2.cdf(2000,2,1000))
print(ncx2.cdf(5000,2,1000))
```

which produces

```
0.998604279948
0.999933004449
0.999933004449
0.999933004449
```

The implementation in scipy is based on Formula  26.4.25 of Abramowitz and Stegun, Handbook of Mathematical  Functions (1966)
(see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/cdflib/cdfchn.f).

There are faster and more accurate algorithms for implementing this function, especially for large non-centrality. For example, R apparently uses Ding (1992) (see http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Chisquare.html). I am wondering if anyone knows if alternative implementations are available as part of a standard python library?

Comment: Perhaps opening an issue in SciPy tracker is the best chance to get this implemented in Python scientific stack.

Comment: Ok, just did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, in case it is useful to someone: the R implementation of the non-central chi-squared distribution can be accessed from python using rpy2 as follows (adapting the example above):

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

stats = importr('stats')

print(stats.pchisq(1200,2,1000)[0])
print(stats.pchisq(1500,2,1000)[0])
print(stats.pchisq(2000,2,1000)[0])
print(stats.pchisq(5000,2,1000)[0])
```

The output is

> 0.998663933426865
>   1.0
>   1.0
>   1.0